# Keyboard Macro (like SAS) Python Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Is it possible to create keyboard macros in Spyder (Python 3.6)?
When I use SAS, there are often snippets of code that I use over and over again, and you can record a keyboard macro.

For example, I have it set up so that I can write

```
proc summary
```

and hit 'tab', and it will automatically update the code to:

```
proc summary data = indata nway;
    var var_to_analyze
    class by_var;
    output out = outdata (drop = _TYPE_ _FREQ_)
        sum (var_to_analyze) = var_name;
run;
```

Seeing I use pieces of code like this quite often, does Spyder have the functionality to create a similar keyboard macros?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) No, unfortunately Spyder doesn't have this functionality at the moment (June 2020).